# Need help connecting C wire please model GSX16S481AA

Tags: electrical, wiring, hvac, air

I had this unit put in about 3 years ago and have had so many issues with thermostats. Can someone help me identify where to place the c wire? It is available behind thermostat but not plugged in. Thank you so much

UPDATE: The pictures I posted originally showed C hooked up, but I came to find out that was actually Y, and I moved it to the correct terminal. I now need to know what transformer to connect the back of C to, and do I need to add the wire or should it be somewhere in front of me for me to simply plug in? Thank you for all your help
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: find the 24 volt transformer, the C wire is on it

Comment: Would you consider helping me for compensation? I want to get this done and I know it is simpler than what it looks like but my brain just won’t understand any of the diagrams I’m looking at ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

Your thermostat *cable* has a yellow wire connected to the C terminal of the system.   It also has a blue wire (normally used for C) not connected to the system.

I emphasize *cable* because we don't know what the yellow (and blue, and all the other) wires are connected to at the other end at the thermostat.

It does look like the C terminal on your system is connected by a blue wire to the common side of the transformer ... I can't be sure from the jumble of wires but I think so.   So the normal way to do it would be the blue wire connects that to the C terminal on your thermostat.

**There are lots of articles telling you what's normal.  You should probably just follow one of them methodicaly.**  Your system, unlike many, seems to have all the necessary terminals and your thermostat cable has all the necessary wires.

Comment: So just connect the blue wire with the yellow wire already in c?

Comment: No.  Connect each colored wire to the appropriate terminal*at both ends* according to the manuals or a good online tutorial.

Comment: Got it. Was hoping the answer was simpler than you telling me to research, as I have no clue what is what but r&r is simple.. thank you for your response

Comment: I am willing to pay for assistance in figuring out these wires. Via Zelle or PayPal to a verified member of this online community, thank you

Comment: Okay so never mind on the C and Y mixup, I had to undo it. So I guess my system just doesn’t have the Y connected. I’m so lost

Answer (score 0):

For time been ignore the electric schematics.

On you pic 1 and 2 is the 24 Volt transformer in top right corner. It shall have 4 wires. Two on one side and two on the other side. 2 wires are input (thus 120 Volt), and two wires are output, thus 24 volt. Turn off power to the AC and do not touch anything.

There is a bar with letters and screws. From left is R which is the 24 Volt from Transformer to the thermostat, then there is C which is the common wire, Then there is G which is for the fan and so on.

Your C tab has a yellow wire that goes to the thermostat. Find it at the thermostat and connect it to the C-tab on thermostat.

Remove the thermostat and inspect how many wires are in that cable.

[image: tstat]

Comment: Okay, so the C wire was actually the Y. I made the switch. So the big mistery for me now is the C wire - what transformer to connect it to and do I need to add the wire or is it already there? Uploading pics so you see what I mean. Thank you for all your help

Comment: Also, thermostat does have 5 wires. The Blue is tucked away waiting for me to use (C wire)